# Getting a array.push to do nothing

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined, void

Trying to figure out a way that if the results of my loop equals undefined, to have my array.push do nothing.   this is my code.

```
  barcodes.sort();
  var first = barcodes.slice(0, (barcodes.length + 1) / 2);
  var second = barcodes.slice(((barcodes.length + 1) / 2), barcodes.length);

  var result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < barcodes.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      result.push(first[i / 2]);
      result.push(second[parseInt(i)/2]);
    }else {

    }
  }
```

getting results when its odd as such: (when even is fine)

```
array results (12) ["1001", "9003", "3001", "9005", "3002", "9006", "3003", "9007", "9001", "9008", "9002", undefined]
```

Comment: Why even call push? Just skip it.

Comment: agree with @PeterB. I cannot see any valid reason to keep the else part of your code

Comment: please add the missing parts and the wanted result.

Comment: *which* `push` does nothing? There are three of them in here. One of them *explicitly* pushes nothing, the other two have a high chance of failing based on what `first` and `second` actually do. It's not clear what this is *supposed* to do, nor what the exact error is.

Comment: `i` will never be `undefined` in your example.

Comment: And inside the loop, i is never going to be undefined

Comment: I think this is the part that i am getting dizzy on lol.   these are my array results

(12) ["1001", "9003", "3001", "9005", "3002", "9006", "3003", "9007", "9001", "9008", "9002", undefined]  but it only happens when I have odd number of results.

Comment: I think we need to know what `barcodes` is, what `first` is and what `second` is. Also what is the end goal here?

Comment: ok, let me update my code snip

Comment: You can loop over every other one rather than test for even indexes: `for (var i = 0; i < barcodes.length; i += 2) `

Comment: `parseInt(i)/2` does not what you seem to expect, as `i` is already an int and the division is outside. You probably wanted to do `Math.floor(i / 2)`

Comment: @BaliBalo `i` will be even so `i/2` is probably sufficient.

Comment: `result.push(second[parseInt(i)/2]);` This is undefined if you have an odd number because `second` is one less than half. So if `barcodes.length == 11`, that second push is pushing `second[5]` when `second.length == 5`. This doesn't exist since indices start at 0

Comment: @adr5240 math.floor still gave me undefined.

Comment: what should happen if you have an odd count of values in `barcode`?

Comment: @NinaScholz the same.  Right not when the complete results of barcodes is an odd array, it adds an "undefined" results.  for example.  on my example.   my array is (11) but it adds an undefined results making it (12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.push(second[parseInt(i)/2]);`

This is undefined if you have an odd number because `second.length` is one less than half of `barcodes`. So if `barcodes.length == 11`, that second push is pushing `second[5]` when `second.length == 5`. This doesn't exist since indices start at 0

```
barcodes = ["1001", "9003", "3001", "9005", "3002", "9006", "3003", "9007", "9001", "9008", "9002"];

barcodes.sort();
var first = barcodes.slice(0, (barcodes.length + 1) / 2);
var second = barcodes.slice(((barcodes.length + 1) / 2), barcodes.length);

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < barcodes.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        result.push(first[i / 2]);
        if(second[(i / 2)]) {
            result.push(second[(i / 2)]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

You could add this line: `if(second[(i / 2)])` to avoid the undefined but again I'm not 100% sure what your end goal is so I'm not sure if this fully answers the question

Comment: This is it.  Thank you SO MUCH

Comment: No worries mate, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the `barcode` array and take an ofset for the second value for pushing.

The adjustment for the length keeps same element groups and add only at the end an `undefined`.

> Examples:
>
> given
>
> ```
> barcode 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
> first   0 1 2 3 4
> second  5 6 7 8
> ```
>
> result
>
> ```
> 0 5   1 6   2 7   3 8   4 undefined
> ```
>
> given
>
> ```
> barcode 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> first   0 1 2 3 4
> second  5 6 7 8 9
> ```
>
> result
>
> ```
> 0 5   1 6   2 7   3 8   4 9
> ```

```js
var barcodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    result = [],
    i,
    l = (barcodes.length + 1) >> 1;

for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    result.push(barcodes[i], barcodes[i + l]);
}

console.log(result);
```